# Pass a div value to JQuery Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

My HTML has a div (#user_info) that outputs a number. I want to use that number in jQuery Progress Bar, so I hid the number using CSS and included the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<div id="progressbar"></div>

<script>

$(function() {
    var valor=parseInt($("#user_info").val(), 10);;
    alert(valor);
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
    value: valor
});
});

</script>
```

Why is the alert function outputing "NaN" and, consequently, the progressbar empty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var valor=parseInt($("#user_info").text(), 10);
```

You can use .val() with input. For div you should use .text() or .html().